# Given a training data set for binary classification, can I estimate the optimal ROC AUC (or any other performance metric)?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, model-evaluation

Assume a labeled dataset $D$ with $n$ observations $X_1, ..., X_n$. Each $X_i$ is represented as an $m$-dimensional features vector: $X_i = [x_{i1}, ..., x_{im}]^\top$. The target labels are $y_i \in \{0,1\}\;\forall i\in[1,n]$, i.e. it's a training dataset for binary classification.

**Question:**
Is it possible to predict an optimal value of the ROC AUC (or any other suitable classifier performance statistic) just based on the training dataset irrespective of any specific choice of classification algorithm, implementation, choice of hyperparameters (model), etc.?

I have researched this question online. While concepts like the effect size (as well as related quantities such as statistical power and significance) seem to be related to my question, I was not able to find any relation between these quantities and classification performance metrics.

**Motivation:**
Assume I build a specific classifier $C$ with the above dataset $D$. I then measure the ROC AUC of this classifier and conclude that it is too low to be acceptable. Now, if I was able to predict an upper limit (an optimal value) of the ROC AUC which is independent of the specifics of my classifier, I could decide whether (a) the classifier or (b) the training dataset is the problem. In the case where the measured ROC AUC is far below the optimal value, it would be wise to improve the classifier. In the other case where the measured ROC AUC is close to the optimal value the classifier is probably fine but there is simply not enough explanation power in my training data. In this latter case, further hyperparameter tuning etc would be a total waste of time because I should rather try to modify my training dataset.

Thanks for any explanation, hints, pointers to (freely accessible) literature, etc.